# Does a Word template (.dot) "travel" with the document?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I have a custom template (`.dotx`) file that I use to create new documents. When I share those documents the “Developer > Templates” window shows my local instance as the associated template, which obviously does not exist on another user’s machine. Yet all the custom styles seem to be available to them.

Do other users need to point the developer tab at a local copy of the template or can they use the seemingly embedded styles?

Answer (score 1):

The styles that you use are embedded in the document, and may be used for further edits, even if the original template does not exist on the computer being used.

When you create a new document based on a particular template, Word actually copies the template `.dotx` file to a new `.docx` file (or loads it into memory as the ‘framework’ of the document), and then saves it as part of the document when the user saves.

A `.dotx` file and a `.docx` file are identical in structure; it is only the difference in extension that turns a `.dotx` into a template that is copied rather than a document that is loaded and modified.

Comment: Thank you.  So for my purposes, the only user who needs the Custom Personal Template is the doc creator, and then all contributors down the line will have the custom styles available to them?

Comment: Correct. And if someone wanted to "recreate" the original template, all they'd have to do is delete the text and Save As... the "empty" document as a "document template".